# JavaFX media player fit to GridPane

Tags: java, javafx-8, gridpane

Hi I have this code for playing video inside JavaFX GridPane. The video is playing perfect, but it is not fit inside GridPane. So how to make it happen?

```
@FXML
private GridPane boxView;

private MediaPlayer player;
private MediaView view;
public void LoadVideo(String videoUrl) {
    URL url = getClass().getResource(videoUrl);
    final Media m = new Media(url.toString());
    this.player = new MediaPlayer(m);
    this.view = new MediaView(player);
    boxView.getChildren().add(view);
    boxView.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    player.play();
}
```

Comment: Just one question why using GridPane ?

Comment: I just want to grow the grid pane with his super parent.